# Surface orientation when integrating a 2-form in Minkowski space

Tags: calculus, exterior-algebra, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $\bf F$ be differential 2-form on a 4-dimensional <s>Lorentzian</s> pseudo-Euclidean manifold $M$ with signature (3, 1) endowed with coordinate functions (t, x, y, z), where t increases in the dimension for which the metric is negative. Let $S$ be a cylindrical surface in M, whose circular faces are parallel to $dx \wedge dy$ and whose sides extend in the $t$ direction from $t=0$ to $t=1$.

Consider the integral of $\bf F$ over $S$. This integral involves the $dx \wedge dy$, $dt \wedge dx$, and $dt \wedge dy$ components of $\bf F$, and can be broken into 3 parts: the two disks, and the side of the cylinder.

Now I can compute the magnitude of each part easily, but I can't figure out the relative orientation. (On which side of the cylinder) does $dt \wedge dx$ face into the cylinder? (On which side) does $- dt \wedge dx$ face in? What about the two circular faces? Does $dx \wedge dy$ face into positive $t$ (and therefore the disk at $t=0$ faces into the cylinder, while the one at $t=1$ faces out)? Or does the circular face at $t=0$ face out of the cylinder when computing this integral?

What if the sign convention flips? And how does one generally determine the orientation of submanifold segments when computing closed integrals on $M$?

Note: I'm using the $-+++$ sign convention, but please specify how the answer changes when you switch sign conventions.

Comment: What is a cylinder in an arbitrary Lorentz manifold? Or is $M = \Bbb R ^4$?

Comment: My apologies, isn't being a pseudo-Riemannian manifold enough to constrain $M$ to be real, and with a (3,1) metric to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R ^4$?

Comment: No. If $(X,g)$ is a Riemann manifold and $g_0$ is the usual Riemann metric on $S^1$ (the circle), consider the manifold $X \times S^1$ with the metric $g- g_0$: it is real, pseudo-Riemannian, of signature $(3,1)$, but clearly not diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ (because, for instance, it is compact, while $\Bbb R^4$ is not).

Comment: Is the signature (3,1) because X is $\mathbb R ^3$? But I think I see the problem, I'd have to say a pseudo-Euclidean space of signature (3,1) to constrain the manifold to $R ^4$, right?

Comment: No, $X$ is not $\Bbb R^3$. The signature comes from the signs in the metric $g - g_0$: in suitable local coordinates on $X \times S^1$, this looks like $\Bbb d x ^2 + \Bbb d y ^2 + \Bbb d z ^2 - \Bbb d t^2$ (the minus comes from the minus preceding $g_0$). This has absolutely nothing to do with $X$ being or not $\Bbb R^3$. And a correction: $X$ must be taken compact in order for my argument involving compactness to hold. For instance, take $X = S^3$ with the usual Riemann structure pulled back from $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: What are $x,y,z,t$? On a manifold, there are in general no prefered coordinates. How did you chose yours? What do you mean that a surface is parallel to $\Bbb d y \wedge \Bbb d z$ (which is a local differential form)? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: The metric signature should not matter at all. The only data going into the orientation is the choice of a volume form.

Comment: What you may be confused by is the fact that if the objects you are integrating are bivectors, then in the (-+++) signature $\mathrm{d}t(X) = - \langle \partial_t, X\rangle$ for arbitrary vector $X$, so that compared to the Euclidean case the "normal vector" would have a sign change. But the area form is the same. // This is one case where it pays to treat "topologically" the objects that are really differential topological in nature and forget about the geometry.

Comment: That's what I want to know. What are the relative orientations of the area forms for a particular volume form? And given the coordinate system I alluded to, which end of the cylinder does $dx \wedge dy$ face into?

Answer (score 1):

From what i understood, your setting is that of $M = (\mathbb{R}^{1,3}, \eta)$, Minkowski four-space together with its metric $\eta$, and want to consider the surface parametrized in the global coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ as

$$S = D_1 \cup C \cup D_2 =  \{(0,x,y,0)|x^2 +y^2 < 1\} \cup \{(t,x,y,0)|t \in [0,1], x^2+y^2 =1\} \cup \{(0,x,y,0)|x^2 +y^2 < 1\}$$

Furthermore assume there is a two-form $F$. It can be pulled back to $S$.

Then
$$
\int_S F = \int_{D_1} F + \int_{C} F + \int_{D_2} F = \\
= \int_{x^2+y^2 < 1} F_{xy}(0,x,y,0) dx \wedge dy + \\
+  \int_{0 \leq t \leq 1,x^2 + y^2 =1 } (F_{tx}(t,x,y,0)  dt\wedge dx + F_{ty}(t,x,y,0)  dt\wedge dy) + \\
+  \int_{x^2+y^2 < 1} F_{xy}(1,x,y,0) dx \wedge dy
$$
There are no choices here.

However, you may orient $S$, that is, choose $(\pm1)$ for each point in $S$ such that it varies smoothly. Since $D_1,C,D_2$ are all connected and orientable, you have three choices of sign. This depends on the physics you are considering. For example, if you want to compute the "magnetic charge" $\int F$ contained in the interior of $S$, you should take $ -D_1 + C + D_2$, but you may have different things in mind.

All of this is independent of the signature of the metric - the metric was not needed.

Comment: Ok, I see the independence of the integral. However, I'm wondering about orientation generally:

Consider a cube in typical Euclidean 3-space: I can pick a normal vector on the $-z$ face that points "outside" the cube, in the $dy \wedge dx$ (i.e.  $- dx \wedge dy$) direction. If I rounded the edges of the cube so it were a topological sphere, I could transport that vector along the surface to the former $x$ face and it would still point "outside" the cube (the $dy \wedge dz$ direction on that face).

What about for the surface of a 3-cube in typical Minkowski space extending along t/x/y?

Comment: That is, which form on the $-t$ face of the cube points "outside," such that were the cube's edges rounded, it could be transported to the $+x$ face still pointing "outside" the cube? $dx \wedge dy$ or $dy \wedge dx$? Does this depend on the metric signature, or is it intrinsic to $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$?

Comment: One may phrase the three-dimensional example as follows: in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there is a orientable volume form $dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$. If $K$ is an oriented surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $NK$ its normal bundle and $\nu$ a no-where vanishing section of this normal bundle, then $dx\wedge dy \wedge dz(\nu,\cdot,\cdot)$ is a volume form on $K$ (this $\nu$ is the unit normal). In the case of Minkowski-space, the situation is essentially the same. If one can pick everywhere non-zero sections of the normal bundle, then one obtains a volume form on an embedded submanifold.